# Grayscale to color transition not working in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-transitions, transition

.picture-box img {

```
display: inline-block;
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
filter: grayscale(100%);
-webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
-moz-filter: grayscale(1);
-o-filter: grayscale(1);
-ms-filter: grayscale(1);
```

}

.picture-box img:hover {

```
filter: none; /* IE6-9 */
filter: grayscale(0);
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
-moz-filter: grayscale(0);
-o-filter: grayscale(0);
-ms-filter: grayscale(0);

-webkit-transition: all 2.0s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 2.0s ease-out;
-ms-transition: all 2.0s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 2.0s ease-out;
transition: all 2.0s ease-out;
```

}

What is wrong with this code? Transition does not work in Firefox. I have 21.0 installed.

Comment: Have you tried adding `top:` values to both? E.g. `top:0;`. If you give me a jsFiddle I can fix it for sure

Comment: Let me put it in a fiddle.

Comment: Do you have the jsFiddle? just link it here :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/amrebel/D9dUA/ Thanx :)

Comment: Couple of things: 

1. Firefox never implemented `-moz-filter` and the only way to get it to work is by using what you used: `filter:url("...")`. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Ffilter#Gecko_notes)

2. Firefox is known not to transition css filter values as you can see [here](http://demosthenes.info/blog/540/Animating-CSS3-Image-Filters) or [here](http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-filters.php).

Comment: not to leave you hanging on it, but you can try adding the unfiltered image to the background of the div and fading out the image inside of it, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cpu6x/ that way you don't need to rely on firefox filters and you get a nice and smooth cross platform transition.

Comment: But it is not working. You code only works when I click somewhere outside (don't know why) and also the transition is very inconsistent... sometimes it fades only to half...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting .picture-box img:hover to this:

```
 filter:grayscale(0%); 
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
 filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
```

You can look it up here. http://www.cheesetoast.co.uk/add-grayscale-images-hover-css-black-white/

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. I want to have the fade in transition. It just goes from grey to color.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Firefox does not yet support CSS filter effects (as of 29.0.1), which is why your first block of code includes a line for an SVG filter, which Firefox does support. Unlike CSS filter effects, the SVG filter cannot be transitioned with CSS.

I don't know of any pure CSS solution for Firefox, but there are a few ways to tackle it with JS (such as dynamically replacing the image with a SVG or HTML5 canvas copy that can be overlaid and faded). This jQuery plugin does a good job of covering all the bases for most browsers: https://github.com/karlhorky/gray